# Req and Res parameters not being received on passport app.use() callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, graphql, passport.js

I'm building the following route on my express middleware:

```
app.use(
    "/graphql",
    passport.authenticate("jwt", { session: false }),
    appGraphQL()
);
```

The route goes through passport for validation and then calls my GraphQL server.

My GraphQL server entry code is:

```
export default (req, res) => {
    console.log("RECEIVED PARAMETERS:")
    console.log(req)
    console.log(res)

    return graphqlHTTP({
        schema: schema,
        graphiql: true,
        pretty: true,
        context: {
            resolvers: null, // Will add my resolvers here
            req: req,
            res: res
        },
        formatError: error => ({
            message: error.message,
            locations: error.locations,
            stack: error.stack,
            path: error.path
        })
    });
};
```

I'm getting null as `req` and `res` parameters.

How can I properly send `req` and `res` to my GraphQL code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are immediately executing `appGraphQL`

```
app.use(
    "/graphql",
    passport.authenticate("jwt", { session: false }),
    (req,res) => appGraphQL(req,res)
);
```

Comment: Indeed it is being executed, but it needs to in order to transact my GraphQL request. I've tried `appGraphQL(req, res)` with no success also...

Comment: I forgot to wrap in an `arrow function`